# CoCreateInstance dont work

Tags: c++, com, wic

I tried to make a Bitmap with direct2d.
The problem is the function CoCreateInstance(...) it wont work

```
 HRESULT Renderer::InitImagingFactory()
{
    if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED))) return E_FAIL;


    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWICImagingFactory,
        reinterpret_cast<void **>(&m_imagingfactory)))) return E_FAIL;

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Define won't work. Won't compile? Won't do what you expect? Lies on the couch all day drinking beer and watching talk shows?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use? Try `CLSID_WICImagingFactory1` or `CLSID_WICImagingFactory2` instead. Also show the rest of initialization.

Comment: Are you experiencing a compiler error, or a runtime error? If the latter, what `HRESULT` value does `CoCreateInstance()` actually return? That will tell you why it is failing.

Comment: You could output the return value of `CoCreateInstance`, which will be a HRESULT that gives a clue as to why the creation failed

Comment: Do fix your coding style, you are returning "it did not work" error codes.  Which is why you could not diagnose the problem.  If a COM function fails then return its failure code.  Automatically makes it debuggable, you've got an HRESULT to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main reasons you could be hitting this.

(1) You need to initialize COM before calling this function. For classic Win32 desktop apps, you'd do this with `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx`. For Windows Runtime platforms you'd use `Windows::Foundation::Initialize`.

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(hr))
    // error
```

(2) You need to make sure you have `_WIN32_WINNT` set correctly for your target platform--see [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).

For a classic Win32 desktop app, you probably want to use the following which initializes WIC2 on platforms that support it or WIC1 otherwise--code found in [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) and [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK)'s `WICTextureLoader`.

```
#include <wincodec.h>

namespace
{
    bool g_WIC2 = false;
}

bool IsWIC2()
{
    return g_WIC2;
}

IWICImagingFactory* GetWIC()
{
    static INIT_ONCE s_initOnce = INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT;

    IWICImagingFactory* factory = nullptr;
    InitOnceExecuteOnce(&s_initOnce,
        [](PINIT_ONCE, PVOID, PVOID *factory) -> BOOL
        {
        #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8) || defined(_WIN7_PLATFORM_UPDATE)
            HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
                CLSID_WICImagingFactory2,
                nullptr,
                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory2),
                factory
                );

            if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
            {
                // WIC2 is available on Windows 10, Windows 8.x, and Windows 7 SP1 with KB 2670838 installed
                g_WIC2 = true;
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                hr = CoCreateInstance(
                    CLSID_WICImagingFactory1,
                    nullptr,
                    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                    __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory),
                    factory
                    );
                return SUCCEEDED(hr) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            }
        #else
            return SUCCEEDED( CoCreateInstance(
                CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
                nullptr,
                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory),
                factory) ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        #endif
        }, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&factory));

    return factory;
}
```

> This uses `InitOnceExecuteOnce` to ensure it's thread-safe. This ensures that the WIC factory is created exactly once no matter which thread calls `GetWIC` first. I'm using a C++11 lambda a.k.a. an *anonymous function* for the callback. The actual pointer to the WIC factory is stored inside the `INIT_ONCE` structure. See [Using One-Time Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686934.aspx)

This code is designed to cover all the possible platform settings.

- When building for Windows Store, Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps, or Xbox then the `_WIN32_WINNT` variable will be set for Windows 8 or later. This would also apply to a classic Win32 desktop application that only supports Windows 8.0 or later.
- When building for Windows 7 `_WIN32_WINNT` will be set to something below Windows 8. The Windows 8.x SDK and Windows 10 SDK WIC header supports both WIC and WIC version 2, but the WIC version 2 defines are not normally defined for Windows 7 or below builds. Therefore, you also use the `_WIN7_PLATFORM_UPDATE` preprocessor symbol in the build settings to get the `wincodec.h` header to define the WIC2 types even with `_WIN32_WINNT` is set to `0x0601` (Windows 7) or `0x0600` (Windows Vista). In this case, you need to handle cases where WIC2 support is not actually installed on the operating system and fallback to use the original WIC factory.
- Otherwise, it just defaults to the default WIC factory which is going to be WIC version 1. This codepath would also build with older Windows SDK than the Windows 8.0 SDK which is the first one with the WIC2 types in `wincodec.h`.

I have the `IsWIC2` function because there are a few places where you need to know if the factory was in fact a WIC2 factory, in particular if you are trying to use the `GUID_WICPixelFormat96bppRGBFloat`, `GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGB`, `GUID_WICPixelFormat64bppRGB`, or `GUID_WICPixelFormat64bppPRGBAHalf` pixel formats. If you aren't using WIC2, then you'll need to use other formats instead.

For details on what's different in WIC vs. WIC2, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280986.aspx) as well as [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/19/windows-imaging-component-and-windows-8/).

Comment: Thank you it works now. But this piece of code looks really unreadable and I realy dont understand what you did there :D

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated the answer with more explanation and references. The code snippet represents years worth of code review from lots of folks at Microsoft, so it really is trying to be 'best of breed'.